# PropertyInfo.GetValue(object) fails with IEnumerable<T> [C#, Reflection]

Tags: c#, reflection, ienumerable, var-dump, propertyinfo

I have the following problem:
I am currently writing the c# equivalent of PHP's `var_dump`-method. It works perfectly with 'simple' classes and structures (and even with arrays).
My only problem is when it comes to other `IEnumerable<T>`, like `List<T>` etc:

The debugger is throwing an `TargetParameterCountException`. My code looks as follows:

```
Type t = obj.GetType(); // 'obj' is my variable, i want to 'dump'
string s = "";
PropertyInfo[] properties = t.GetProperties();

for (int i = 0; i < properties.Length; i++)
{
    PropertyInfo property = properties[i];

    object value = property.GetValue(obj); // <-- throws exception

    if (value is ICollection)
    {
        // Code for array parsing - is irrelevant for this problem
    }
    else
        s += "Element at " + i + ": " + value.GetType().FullName + " " + value.ToString() + "\n";
}

return s;
```

I know, that i can somehow fetch indices with `PropertyInfo.GetIndexParameters()`, but I did not figured out, how to use it correctly.

**Edit:** I also want to note that I neither know the size of the IEnumerable, nor the Type T at compile time.

Comment: try to use this overload: `property.GetValue(obj, null)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the type implementing `IEnumerable`.  Rather it's about the type having an indexer.  Indexers are considered properties, but they're special properties that need to be given the parameter of the index when getting their value.  If you don't, it errors as you're seeing here.

You can use `GetIndexParameters()` and check the count of the returned array to determine if the property is an indexer.  This will let you either skip that property (which is what I assume you'll want to do here), or use it to get its values.

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly sure if this is your problem, but according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194385%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> You call the GetValue(Object) overload to retrieve the value of a non-indexed property; if you try to retrieve the value of an indexed property, the method throws a TargetParameterCountException exception.

From the example on the same page:

> ```
>      if (prop.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0)
>         Console.WriteLine("   {0} ({1}): {2}", prop.Name,
>                           prop.PropertyType.Name,
>                           prop.GetValue(obj));
>      else
>         Console.WriteLine("   {0} ({1}): <Indexed>", prop.Name,
>                           prop.PropertyType.Name);
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `GetIndexParameters()` method of `PropertyInfo` to determine whether the property is indexed, and if it is, either skip it, or go back to the drawing board and see how you can generate the index(es) that it needs in order to return a meaningful value without failing.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the reference to the IEnumerable and not only it's items you can get it using :

```
if (propertyInfo.GetMethod.IsPublic)
{

    var value = propertyInfo.GetMethod.Invoke(Instance, null);
}
```